# Issue when attempting to add Geo Location Data - "cannot get geometry object from data you send to the geometry field"

Tags: geolocation

I am receiving an error message when I attempt the following

create table Mycustomers3 (
Name varchar(255) not null primary key,
Gender varchar(255) not NULL,
Address varchar(255) not NULL,
Geo_location_address point
);
insert into Mycustomers3(name,gender,address,geo_location_address) values
('Cust One','female','6 The Street, Bradford','50.82738,-0.14007'),
('Cust Two','male','Flat 99, White Road, Cornwall','50.81831,-0.10645');
select * from Mycustomers3;

it returns this error
"cannot get geometry object from data you send to the geometry field"

I read somewhere that it maybe something to do with NULL data but not sure how to overcome this.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is you database type and version? The coordinates are in latitude / longitude?

Comment: I need it to be executable on PostgreSQL and PostGIS.  Yes they are.  Thank you

Comment: Try `ST_PointFromText('POINT(50.82738 -0.14007)', 4326)` when you insert data for your `point` column. It is also possible that you have to use `geometry` data type.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give it a try.